# Dapper return reversed date format

Tags: c#, sql, orm, dapper

Dapper returns date type column in different format than it is stored in database.

format in database ----> **2012-05-19** 15:27:00.000

dapper returns --------> **19-05-2012** 15:27:00.000

```
var l = this.db.Query<myObject>("select id, received from myTable where( received between @d1 and @d2)",
                                                 new { @d1 = d1, @d2 = d2, }).ToList();

string  d1 = 2011-01-18 00:00:00
string  d2 = 2014-07-18 23:59:59

 public class myObjectIs 
 {
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string received { get; set; }

 }
```

**received - datatime type columm**

Has Dapper got predefined format of date type to return?
If yes, how to change it?

Thanks.

Comment: If the data type in the database is date, don't worry about it.  c# has date formatting tools available.  Use one.

Comment: DateTime values have no format. It is your program that display the DateTime value in a 'FORMAT' However, if the field `received` is a date why do you store it in a string? Use a DateTime variable instead

Comment: A datetime in a database **has no format**; it is a number. Are you storing it as a string? or as a datetime?

Comment: Also: what **exactly** are `d1` and `d2` here? are they `string`? or `DateTime` ? and again: what **exactly** is the defined type of the `received` column?

Comment: updated my qyestion: d1 and d2 are strings, receive is datatime

Comment: @piowtarn k; **why** are `d1` and `d2` strings? they really really really shouldn't be

Comment: I'm going to get the necromancer badge, here goes:
OP's question still seems unanswered. I am facing a similar issue. At the db level, my columns are dates. My query returns the dates in the exact format I want and I am also using Dapper to map the result back into class where the properties for those dates are of type string (since from the db I already have it in the format I want). The application is for reports, I just want to display the data, there is no input. However Dapper is converting the format on mine too. I would rather let sql do the formatting, rather than have to do it in c#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem appears to be that you are using a `string` for `received`, instead of a `DateTime`. Dates/times **do not have a format**, until you actually force them to become a string - at which point they are no longer dates/times. A date/time is **just a number**.

As a last ditch effort, if all inbuilt conversions are exhausted, dapper uses `Convert.ChangeType` to thunk between types. This will cause regular `ToString()` to be used in this case. If you don't want this (and you shouldn't want this): declare `received` to be a `DateTime`:

```
public DateTime received { get; set; }
```

Likewise, from comments:

> d1 and d2 are strings

They should not be; they should be `DateTime` too:

```
DateTime d1 = ..., d2 = ...
```

or at the very least, you should parse it inside your data access code:

```
new { d1 = [someparse(d1)], @d2 = [someparse(d2)], }
```

where `[someparse]` is probably something involving `DateTime.Parse` or `DateTime.ParseExact`